# How to allow JSONWriter to accept an XML formatted key?

Tags: java, xml, json

I am using org.json.JSONWriter in Java. I need to have an XML value for a certain key.

```
StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter();
JSONWriter w = new JSONWriter(writer);
w.object()
    .key("data").value(xmlContents)
.endObject();
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Running that code where `xmlContents` is valid XML file contents. **The resulting JSONObject ends up escaping all the closing tags of my XML.** The XML is originally

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><my_xml><version>2.0</version><date>2013-01-16T20:44:31Z</date></my_xml>
```

and turns into

```
{"data":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><my_xml><version>2.0<\/version><date>2013-01-16T20:44:31Z<\/date><\/my_xml>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but try using `setHtmlSafe()` for your JasonWriter..

From JavaDocs:
setHtmlSafe()

Configure this writer to emit JSON that's safe for direct inclusion in HTML and XML documents. This escapes the HTML characters <, >, & and = before writing them to the stream. Without this setting, your XML/HTML encoder should replace these characters with the corresponding escape sequences.

Comment: Can you provide link please? I don't see that method anywhere.

Comment: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html

Comment: I'm using org.json.JSONWriter unfortunately, not google library

Comment: I am sorry you are using different library. I don't know how to solve it but once quick suggestion - you may want to use org.json.JSONStringer and see if does something differently... Good luck!